# Implementing Twitter in iPhone using OAuth?

Tags: iphone, ios4, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am trying to implement Twitter in my App using OAuth... I have all the code in my button click method... But as soon as I click on the button my app gets killed on the following line of code

```
UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];
```

There is no message in the debug window except CFrelease... What am I possibly doing wrong?

```
if(!_engine){  

_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];  
_engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;  
_engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  
} 

if(![_engine isAuthorized]){  

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];  

if (controller){  
[self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];  
}  
}
```

this error shows up

> Xcode could not locate source file:
>   OAMutableURLRequest.m

Answer (score 0):

I use sharekit for all this nonsense. It took me 10 minutes tonight to get a range of service working. getsharekit.com